# Infographic Resume, Yea or Nay?

Tags: professionalism, resume

Is an infographic resume suitable when applying for a position? I'm currently looking for graduate training programs, supply chain, buying, and marketing positions.

Comment: NAY! (unless your job involves only creating infographics)

Comment: I think while such a resume is creative, it would probably send the wrong message to employers.

Comment: It's not a duplicate because the question referenced only talks of graphics including in a resume, not graphics actually BEING the resume, and a specific graphic at that.

Comment: about as suitable as handwriting your resume in calligraphy on a leaf

Comment: It is certainly suitable if you are paid to write one of those BS articles on "how to make your resumes stand out from the crowd" or if your goal is to expedite your resume's journey to the hiring manager's trashbin.

Answer (score 8):

Unless you're looking for a job making Info-graphics, don't do it.

There are accepted practices for resumes and CV's because it allows HR professionals and hiring managers to swiftly look them over and pass them on or eliminate them.  While you may get some attention with an info-graphic, you're more likely to annoy those reading it and get it thrown out.

Remember, anything that interrupts a potential employer's workflow creates more work for them and doesn't bode well for you.

Comment: So I guess for other jobs that I'm keen other than marketing, I'll just have to stick to the old plain text. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: If you're doing going for marketing, it might be worth it to INCLUDE one (as opposed to actually being an infographic resume) because you still have to go through the HR gatekeepers. Perhaps as part of a portfolio (that you could include a link to in your resume).

Answer (score 3):

It's a gamble, unless ([as Christopher Estep points out](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/75480/10905)) you're looking for a job making Info-graphics.

If HR and the hiring managers are looking at a stack of 100+ resumes that all more or less look the same, **you'll stand out**.  Whether that means you'll get more consideration or be tossed aside is the gamble.

You mentioned marketing positions - showing you know how to stand out from a crowd and get noticed may be useful.

A big challenge will be to come up with an info graphic that is on topic, useful, and information-dense.  A successful graphic would show that you'd be a good fit for the position even without your design skills.  That's a difficult feat.

If the company uses some sort of HR keyword searching program, your application will probably do poorly - keyword searching programs rarely deal with images well.

Comment: yea exactly. that's one of my concerns. Especially the keyword searching program.